# Errors when switching scenes in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my little Flash project, I use the Enter Frame Gameloop commands, and I use hittestobject and such then put that function in to the game loop. However, When switching scenes I am bombarded with errors because the objects included in the functions are not on screen anymore. My question is how can I either take those functions out of the game loop when changing from that specific scene, or write the code so it only includes that one specific scene. Like: if current frame = 2, or something in real code form. Thankyou so much I am very appreciative for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
function gameLoop(evnt:Event){
    try{
        //Write your all codes

    }catch(err:Error){

    }
}
```

Use `try`/ `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the way you change scenes.

Based on your description,I guess the way you change scenes is to go to different frames.Am I right?

If I am right,I think you can declare a variable to mark if you need to do the hittestobject function or other operations.

such as:

```
gameloop(){
    if(!changing)
        a.hitTestObject(b)
}
```